# Using second argument of php assert function throws compile time exception via HHVM

Tags: php, assert, hhvm

By PHP 5.4.8, assert function has a second argument as description.

I wonder why HHVM throws exception when filling the second argument!

It says: `Too many arguments for assert(), expected 1`

Is there any configuration I miss?

Comment: You probably should be filing a bug report or checking for known issues relating to Assert.

Comment: HHVM will always be out-of-sync with mainline PHP by definition. They simply haven't added support for this yet.

Comment: @GordonM how could I check that? list of known issues

Comment: Did you try googling hhvm known issues?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of HHVM should, in theory, support pretty much every feature present in PHP 5.5. This includes that second argument for the `assert` function. I can't find a link to support this statement at the moment, but I will edit and add it if I find it later.

Make sure you're running the latest version of HHVM (3.2 at the time when I'm writing this). If you are and you still have this error, search for this issue on [HHVM's GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm) and, if none is there that fits this problem, create one. Since HHVM is open-source, you can even fix it yourself, it would be a great exercise :) .

Comment: Yeah I use HHVM 3.2 and also create an issue on their page.